# How to do a simple 2d map with z-levels?

Tags: dictionary, 2d

I know how to do a simple 2d map and i want to add z-levels.
I'm try this:

```
map = {}
for z = 1, 10 do
 map[z] = {}
  for x = 1, 10 do
   map[x] = {}
   for y = 1, 10 do
    map[x][y][z] = 0
   end
  end
end
```

But this isn't not worked. So, how i can make a simple small "3d" map? Where i mistake? 
Feel free to use your own code but if you can, do it on lua please.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my mind on this for 2 hours and now i do this.
Works fine:

```
map = {}
for x = 1, 10 do
 map[x] = {}
 for y = 1, 10 do
  map[x][y] = {}
  for z = 1, 10 do
   map[x][y][z] = z
  end
 end
end
```